# Sorting an Excel Column by value

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a column with ID values, like these:

```
50
14G
44
2X
22
```

I would like to sort it by "digit value" using VBA, so I get a list like this

```
14G
22
2X
44
50
```

Since numbers should come before letters, and digits' relevance comes from their position. However, if I use Range().Sort I get a list like this:

```
22
44
50
14G
2X
```

Which is how Excel sorts it alphabetically. Is there a way to sort it the way I want it, short of writing a sort function myself?

Comment: You can add helper column with formula `=""&A1` and sort using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you format all of the values as **Text** you will be able to sort using the **Sort numbers and numbers store as text differently** option. This produces the results you are looking for.

[image: Sort Numbers as text]

Of course, you will lose the benefit of dealing with true numbers and will have to watch out for lookups that are seeking a true number and not text-that-looks-like-a-number but as your values are already mixed, this might not be a bad thing.

Comment: But how can I force a VBA script to view the cell's content as a Text?

Comment: Use VBA to convert them into text and put the [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx)'s `DataOption:=xlSortNormal` option.